# Using python to add an additional sheet with formulas to each xlsb file in a folder

Tags: python, excel-formula, directory, worksheet, xlsb

I have a folder with 73 xlsb files. I need to do the following to each of these files:

1. Add a new sheet to each of these files and rename it to "Data Values".
2. Into the newly created sheet, I must add the following:

| Cell | Formulae / Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | "Sale date" |
| B1 | "Customer ID" |
| C1 | "Customer Name" |
| D1 | "Sale amount" |
| E1 | "Percent of target" |
| A2 | ='Main Calculation'!B3 |
| B2 | 1011 |
| C2 | "ABC Desserts" |
| D2 | ='Addl Calc'!H30 |
| E2 | ='Addl Calc'!I30 |

Would there be Python code that could achieve this?

Comment: did you try the `openpyxl` module.  where is the code ?  where are you stuck ?